# Efficient way to split strings in separate rows (creating an edgelist)

Tags: r, string, split

I currently have the following problem. I work with Web-of-Science scientific publication and citation data, which has the following structure: A variable "SR" is a string with the name of a publication, "CR" a variable with a string containing all cited references in the article, separated by a ";".

My task now is to create an edgelist between all publications with the corresponding citations, where every publication and citation combination is in a single row. I do it currently with the following code:

```
# Some minimal data for example
pub <- c("pub1", "pub2", "pub3")
cit <- c("cit1;cit2;cit3;cit4","cit1;cit4;cit5","cit5;cit1")
M <- cbind(pub,cit)
colnames(M) <- c("SR","CR")

# Create an edgelist
cit_el <- data.frame() # 
for (i in seq(1, nrow(M), 1)) { #   i=3
  cit <- data.frame(strsplit(as.character(M[i,"CR"]), ";", fixed=T), stringsAsFactors=F) 
  colnames(cit)[1] <- c("SR")
  cit$SR_source <- M[i,"SR"]
  cit <- unique(cit)
  cit_el <- rbind(cit_el, cit)
}
```

However, for large datasets of some 10k+ of publications (which tend to have 50+ citations), the script runs 15min+. I know that loops are usually an inefficient way of coding in R, yet didn't find an alternative that produces what I want.

Anyone knows some trick to make this faster?

Comment: I think you may want to try `tidyr:: separate` which separate a string in multiple columns using a separator. And this in the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt. I haven't compared the speeds of different approaches yet.

First is the artificial data with 10k pubs, 100k possible citations, max is 80 citations per pub.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

pubCount = 10000

citCount = 100000 

maxCitPerPub = 80

pubList <- paste0("pub", seq(pubCount))

citList <- paste0("cit", seq(citCount))

cit <- sapply(sample(seq(maxCitPerPub), pubCount, replace = TRUE),
               function(x) str_c(sample(citList, x), collapse = ";"))

data <- data.table(pub = pubList,
                   cit = cit)
```

For processing, I use stringr::str_split_fixed to split the citations into columns and use data.table::melt to collapse the columns.

```
temp <- data.table(pub = pubList, str_split_fixed(data$cit, ";", maxCitPerPub))

result <- melt(temp, id.vars = "pub")[, variable:= NULL][value!='']
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great and fast. I see I should more often work with data.tables. The only thing is that I have to define the maximum numbers of cit upfront, but that's no problem. And it is orders of magnitude faster than my loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any quicker but if I'm understanding correctly this should give the desired result

```
rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(M), function(i){
data.frame(SR_source = M[i, 'SR'], SR = strsplit(M[i, 'CR'], ';'))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Doing it via lapply is actually a good idea. For the code here, however, I get a warning message:

Warning messages:
1: In data.frame(SR_source = M[i, "SR"], SR = strsplit(M[i, "CR"],  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

And the output here only shows the first pair of SR and CR. I would instead need an output format like:

pub1 - cit1
pub1 - cit2
pub1 - cit3
pub2 - cit2